Rounding when ULP 1 - Java and C++
The reason of the question originated from differences in the results that I observed when computing std::exp(x) in C++ against Math.exp(x) in Java (with x of type double). I noticed that the algorithm used for computing the exp() are different between the two languages. However, I believe that they both ensure that the rounding error is ULP 1.
So the question is the following:
how does the rounding happen when ULP is set to 1? How does it decide if rounding up or down? and "who" does the choice?
I would like to obtain the same exact results of Java when computing the exp(x) in C++.
If I replicate in C++ the exact algorithm in that Java uses within Math.exp() (which actually delegate to fdlibm), will I obtain identical results between the two langauges?
Or a consequence of the ULP 1 is that the rounding up or down is arbitrary and therefore it does not depend on the specific algorithm?
Note: my understanding of ULP 1 is that if the results of a mathematical function is, let's assume, f(x) = 0.55 and the floating point numbers closes to it are 0.52 and 0.56, then (even if 0.56 would be the optimal choice) the results could be either 0.52 or 0.56.
Further side question: I also observed that switching in C++ between x86 and x64, does change the results of exp(x), aligning it sometimes with the results given by Java. Why does the results of exp(x) changed in C++ between x86 and x64 built? Compiler is MSVC 14.16.27023
Update: I have used the implementation of fdlibm for exp() (code provided in https://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_exp.c) and I do actually get a result which is different both from std::exp() of C++ and Math.exp() of Java. The specific numbers that I'm trying are:
exp(-0.271153846153846134203746487401076592504978179931640625)
exp(-0.03076923076923077093880465326947160065174102783203125)

Are you compiling the x86 and x64 programs exactly the same (except for the x86 / x64 part)? What compiler options are you using?

ULP stands for "units in the last place" so in a double precision floating point value with a 53-bit mantissa it would be only in the 53rd binary place (or 54th, I'm not sure, I think there's an implied 1-bit at the beginning). So 0.52 and 0.56 is not a good example.

@DavidConrad, the context in which that's discussed seems to suggest that the OP knows that, and is consciously simplifying the example to make their understanding clear -- and I think their understanding is, in fact, correct (that either of the two nearest floating-point numbers to the real result is allowable with an error of 1 ulp)

@LouisWasserman Fair enough, then.

@DavidConrad it is indeed a simple example

@TedLyngmo exactly the same program, yes (just switch the drop down setting in Visual Studio Code at the top of the window). Which specific details do you want to know about the compiler options?

@Albert Re: "Which specific details do you want to know about the compiler options?" - I would like for you to add to the question exactly what compiler options that are used in both cases.

@TedLyngmo can you help me to identify the compiler options? I tried to look into the properties, but didn't find much useful information.

@Albert You need to make your IDE output the exact commands it's using to compile and link. I don't use VS Code myself so I can't tell you how to do it, but it is possible.

@Albert, when analyzing exactness, preciseness and ULP of FP, it is useful to use base 16 output as in -0.271153846153846134203746487401076592504978179931640625 --> -0x1.15a95a95a95a9p-2.


Note: my understanding of ULP 1 is that if the results of a mathematical function is, let's assume, f(x) = 0.55 and the floating point numbers closes to it are 0.52 and 0.56, then (even if 0.56 would be the optimal choice) the results could be either 0.52 or 0.56.

This is not correct. The C++ standard does not specify how accurately the mathematical routines in the standard library must be calculated, and implementations vary. And note the plural: There are multiple implementations. Your question refers to “std::exp(x) in C++” as if it were a single thing. It is not. There are different implementations of exp used in different implementations of C++. A single C++ compiler may even be linked with different choices of libraries containing implementations of std::exp.
I am less familiar with the specifications of the Java standard in this regard, although I know that its StrictMath class is defined with respect to fdlibm version 5.3, so it should give reproducible results across different implementations.
The property you describe, where the result computed for f(x) is one of the two floating-point numbers immediately bounding the mathematical f(x), is called faithful rounding. (There may be slight variations in the definition of “faithful rounding” used in various places.)
It is common that implementations of math routines are not faithfully rounded. Errors of multiple ULP may be common, and greater errors may exist.
It is unlikely you can get the same results in Java and C++ except by using a fdlibm version 5.3 implementation with C++.
For accuracy in math routines, the best goal is correct rounding, which means the computed result for f(x) equals the result of rounding the mathematical f(x) to the nearest value representable in the floating-point format using a specified rounding rule. (The most common rounding rule is round-to-nearest, ties-to-even. Other rounding rules include round upward, round downward, and round toward zero.) Correct rounding is generally hard, because a mathematical function may have points arbitrarily close to a point where rounding switches, so there is no finite limit on how accurately a function may have to be computed to determine which side of the rounding point the value falls on. Each function has to be considered individually.
For the format commonly used for double, IEEE-754 binary64, humans do not yet know whether all of the math library routines can be computed with correct rounding in a known bounded time. The Core-MATH project is working on this and has produced correctly rounded implementations of many of the math library routines, but not yet all.
exp is one of the easier functions, so it is done; a correctly rounded implementation is available. However, you can expect a correctly rounded implementations to differ from the fdlibm routine used by Java. So conformance between languages and prior implementations is actually an impediment to improving the math library.

If I replicate in C++ the exact algorithm in that Java uses within Math.exp() (which actually delegate to fdlibm), will I obtain identical results between the two [languages]?

That can be done, but it can be complicated. Suppose fdlibm has some code y = (((a*x + b)*x + c)*x + d;. You can reproduce that code in C++. However, the C++ standard does not require that expression to be evaluated using double arithmetic even if all the variables are double. It allows the C++ implementation to use extra precision. If you wish to reproduce fdlibm results exactly in C++, you will need to learn about floating-point evaluation in C++ and tightly control it.
Additional Notes
The text “how does the rounding happen when ULP?” appears to be ungrammatical. “ULP” is not a verb, and I do not know what you mean by this.

How does it decide if rounding up or down? and "who" does the choice?

A mathematical software engineer analyzes the function, the hardware and software available to them, and crafts an implementation. Implementations of math library routines commonly include code for argument reduction and evaluation of a polynomial. The polynomial is often a minimax polynomial. The engineer makes decisions about the precision with which to perform the argument reduction and the polynomial evaluation, the degree to use for the polynomial, endpoints of the polynomial in case they split the function domain into subintervals, and so on. In the end, they end up with code that approximates the function f. Whether rounding up or down occurs for any particular input is a happenstance of the behavior of the approximation at that point.


edited the question on “how does the rounding happen when ULP?” there was a missing last bit. I'm asking how it decides if rounding up or down when the set ULP for a specific math function (exp in this case) is equal to 1.



I don't understand why you are saying that my understanding of ULP 1 is not correct, when you then define it as the "faithful rounding"



you say " The C++ standard does not specify how accurately the mathematical routines in the standard library must be calculated" but https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Errors-in-Math-Functions.html seems to mention (as the case of my question) a ULP of 1 for exp()



I believed the implementation used in C++ is: https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_exp.c.html



you say "However, the C++ standard does not require that expression to be evaluated using double arithmetic even if all the variables are double." I believed that basic operations as addition, subtraction, multiplication and division  are guaranteed (by the IEEE standard) to generate identical results among different programming language which adhere to the standard (I did not notice any difference, up to now, produced by those operations, between C++ and Java).


@Albert: 1. The phrasings “ULP is 1”, “ULP 1”, and “ULP is set to 1” are not commonly used. You appear to be saying some function implementation has ULP 1 or, say, ULP 3, if there is a known bound on the errors in its results that is 1 ULP or 3 ULP, respectively. This is not a normal use of ULP because ULP is basically a measurement unit, like a meter or a gram, not the amount of error in a function. One ULP is the position value of the least significant digit in the significand of a floating-point representation. Nearly equivalently, it is the distance between adjacent representable numbers…

… at a certain point. So, for example, in binary64, the ULP of 1 is 2^−52. We might say the error bound of a particular sin implementation is 3 ULP to mean that sin(x) differs from sine x by at most 3 ULP. We would not say that “the ULP of sin is 3.” And we cannot set the ULP of an implementation. It is not a parameter we can adjust up or down. We design a sin implementation and try to make it pretty good, and the amount of error the implementation has is a property of that implementation, not something we can “set” to some number of ULP.

@Albert: 2. Faithful rounding and an error bound of 1 ULP are not the same thing. If 1.1, 1.2, and 1.3 are adjacent representable values and f(x) is 1.2, then returning 1.3 for f(x) has an error of 1 ULP, since the distance from 1.2 to 1.3 is 1 ULP, but a faithfully rounded implementation must return 1.2. I did not fully define it in the answer, but, when a function value is exactly representable, faithful rounding returns that value exactly. The error of faithful rounding is therefore always less than 1 ULP; it is never 1 ULP. (Note the converse is not necessarily true, depending…

… on the definition of ULP. That is, the fact that the error of an implementation is always less than 1 ULP does not mean it is faithfully rounded. If .95, 1, and 1.1 are representable values, the ULP between 1 and 1.1 is .1. Suppose f(x) is 1.01. Then, if f(x) returns .95, it is less than 1 ULP from f(x), since 1.01 − .95 = .06, which is less than .1. So the error in f(x) is less than 1 ULP in this case, but f(x) is not faithfully rounded because faithful rounding requires that f(x) return 1 or 1.1.)

@Albert: 3. The link you give is for information about the GNU C Library, which contains one implementation of the Standard C Library. There are other implementations of the Standard C Library, such as those provided by Apple or Microsoft.

@Albert: 4. Again, that is one implementation of the exp routine. There are others. After a source code for a program is compiled, the object module(s) are linked to make an executable program. The linking can link with the GNU Standard C Library or an Apple library or a Microsoft library or a library you wrote yourself or other libraries, depending on what is available for the target platform and other circumstances. So even with one compiler there may be multiple choices for which exp routine is used. There is not just one exp implementation.

@Albert: C++ 2020 draft N4849 clause 7.1 [expr.pre] paragraph 6 says “The values of the floating-point operands and the results of floating-point expressions may be represented in greater precision and range than that required by the type; the types are not changed thereby.” This means that an expression using floating-point may be evaluated using more precision than the nominal types in it. The fact you have not observed it merely means you have not observed it, not that it is not allowed. The IEEE-754 standard does specify operations that would produce identical results…

… However, the C++ standard does not specify that C++ implementations must conform to the IEEE-754 standard (it is an option). You should also understand that how a programming language binds to IEEE-754 is not specified by IEEE-754. A programming language could say that +, -, * and / evaluate expressions using some crude but fast approximations while _+, _-, _*, and _/ perform the IEEE-754 operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. So just because you see a*b + c in source code, do not think those must mean IEEE-754 operations.

@Albert Expanding on what Eric said about point 5,
yes, IEEE-754 guarantees correctly-rounded
results for operations like +,  -, *, and /,
but what that means is, correctly-rounded for individual operations,
to the precision limit of a particular type.
Consider the operations a = b / c; a += d.
If a, b, c, and d are all of type double, then yes, for
particular values of b, c, and d, the result a will be
exactly determined by IEEE-754 rules.

But now consider collapsing the expression to d = a / b + c.
In C and C++, at least, the compiler is allowed to do you a favor by
computing an intermediate result x = a / b in higher precision
(perhaps equivalent to long double),
then adding c and rounding back to double, giving a
properly-rounded version of the mathematical result
a ÷ b + c,
without suffering intermediate rounding of the first quotient.
I can give you values of a, b, and c for which this makes a difference.

(This greater-precision-for-intermediate-results ability essentially
gives you the same sort of benefit as the IEEE-754
fma
operation, but for arbitrary expressions.  But there's a cost to this "optimization" as well, since it provides additional opportunities for confusion, when seemingly identical sequences of operations, expressed slightly differently, yield slightly different results)

I said "yes, for particular values of b, c, and d, the result a will be exactly determined by IEEE-754 rules", and it's too late for me to edit that comment, but I should have said "will most likely be exactly determined", because as Eric said, C and C++ do not require that compilers conform perfectly to IEEE-754 at all. (Also, whoops, my "collapsed expression" scrambled the usage of a, b, c, and d. Hopefully you see what I meant.)

Let me see if I got the understanding of ULP. Let's assume that the error bound of a specific function implementation, f(x), is 1 ULP.
Assume 0.98 0.99 1.0 1.2 are adjacent representable values and f(x) = 1.01. Then, since the f(x) result fall within 1.0 and 1.2, 1 ULP corresponds to a value of 0.2. It follows that f(x) could be implemented such that its final (rounded) output can be either 0.98 or 0.99 or 1.0 or 1.2 as all of these values have a distance of less than 0.2 from the true result 1.01. Is my understanding correct?

@Albert Re "It is common that implementations of math routines are not faithfully rounded" For an overview of commonly used math libraries, see: Brian Gladman, Vincenzo Innocente, John Mather, and Paul Zimmermann, "Accuracy of Mathematical Functions in Single, Double, Double Extended, and Quadruple Precision", August 2024, hal-03141101v7

@Albert: Yes, returning any of the representable values .98, .99, 1.0, or 1.2 for f(x) when f(x) is 1.01 conforms to the specification that the maximum error for f is at most 1 ULP, with the understand that .2 is the ULP for 1.01 in this hypothetical format. Note that there is nothing special here. Asserting the maximum error for f is 1 ULP is essentially just an English statement, and the implementor could choose other statements to make. They could say the maximum error for f is at most .00000034% (relative to f(x)) or the maximum error is at most .00035 (absolute difference) or…

… the maximum error is less than .505 ULP for values in a primary domain of f (e.g., −π/2 to +π/2 for sine) but the maximum error outside that is less than 3 ULP. These are simply statements the implementor writes to specify something about their implementation. Sometimes, when I have written a function, I might know something like the argument reduction causes an error in the calculated final result less than  .6 ULP, and the approximating polynomial has an error less than 1.3•2^−25, but the calculation of it has an error less than 3.7•2^−24 + .5 ULP…

… So maybe I could write a statement to users that implementation has an error less than 4.35•2^−24 + 1.1 ULP over its entire domain and less than 4.35•2^−24 + .5 ULP in its primary domain (where no argument reduction error occurs), and I could possibly supplement that with additional limits in specific intervals of argument reduction. But that would be complicated, and few people do it. So, even when an implementor knows the error bounds well, they often just make a broad statement, like the error is less than 1.6 UP, even though they could refine that.

Thank you Eric, I understood. One last doubt: in this last example we said that with 1 ULP all the results .98, .99, 1.0, or 1.2 could be fine for f(x) = 1.01.  If instead the error bound was 0.5 ULP then only the results .98, .99, 1.0 would be allowed. However, this seems to not align with  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html where 0.5 ULPs seems a synonym for 'correctly rounded' as: "If a method always has an error less than 0.5 ulps, the method always returns the floating-point number nearest the exact result; such a method is correctly rounded. "

@Albert: That document is wrong. It is not uncommon for people to make mistakes regarding behaviors that occur at boundaries where the spacings between floating-point numbers change. Correct rounding with round-to-nearest  guarantees error of at most ½ ULP, but error of at most ½ ULP does not guarantee correct rounding.

@Albert: On second thought, that document may be correct for its specific context where only binary floating-point is considered, since IEEE-754 binary64 is the type used in Java. In a decimal floating-point format, we could have the representable numbers around 1 being .98, .99, 1.0, and 1.1, and then the ULP from 1 to 1.1 is .1 yet .99 is less than ½ ULP away from 1.01. However, when we limit this to binary floating-point, the ULP changes only by a factor of 2, not 10…

… If u is the ULP at 1 (u = 2^−52 for IEEE-754 binary64), the representable numbers around 1 are 1−1½u, 1−u, 1−½u, 1, 1+u, 1+2u, 1+3u,… If some f(x) is slightly over 1, say 1+e, then its distance from the next representable number under 1 is (1+e) − (1−½u) = ½u + e. Thus, if the error is less than ½ ULP, the result must be correctly rounded—for binary floating-point…

… Note there is still a flaw in their statement; they say if the error is less than ½ ULP, the function is correctly rounded, but this does not cover the case where the error is ½ ULP. Correctly rounded functions may have errors of exactly ½ ULP, so saying the error is less than ½ ULP implies the function is correctly rounded is not a complete characterization of correctly rounded functions; it is a sufficient condition but not a necessary one.
